# React hooks using an existing function inState

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a React component that uses drag and drop to upload a file based on this tutorial: https://blog.logrocket.com/create-a-drag-and-drop-component-with-react-dropzone/
and I am not too familiar with React Hooks component types.

In my customization, I want to hide the drag and drop container once the file is dropped in the area and display just the file container.

The state I've created for this is `const [isDropped, setIsDropped] = useState(false);`

This is the function which displays the file once it is dropped in:

```
  const fileDrop = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const files = e.dataTransfer.files;
    if (files.length) {
      handleFiles(files);
    }
  };
```

Finally, this is an abbreviated version of what I am trying to accomplish:

#### Drop.js

```
      {!isDropped ? (
        <div
          className="drop_container"
          onDragOver={dragOver}
          onDragEnter={dragEnter}
          onDragLeave={dragLeave}
          onDrop={fileDrop}
          // Alternate onDrop ~~~> onDrop={() => setIsDropped(!isDropped)}
          onClick={fileInputClicked}
        > 

            <p className="drop_message">
              <input
                ref={fileInputRef}
                className="file-input"
                type="file"
                multiple
                onChange={filesSelected}
              />
             Drop your file (format pdf max 20MB)
            </p>

              ) : (

            <div className="file-display-container">
                <div className="file-type">{fileType(data.name)}</div>
            </div>
             
           )}
```

My idea was in `onDrop` to set the state  `onDrop={() => setIsDropped(!isDropped)}`, however onClick is already being used by the fileUpload function.

My question is how can I combine the function into my state or how would I add the state to the current onClick event?

Answer (score 0):

If You are holding the selected files in state then you do not need to use any state for hold value like , user has dropped the file or not, You can just the check like if there some value in state (which using to hold the selected file value) then you can disable the drop and click event.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to fix this issue by setting the state inside of the `fileDrop` function after reading this React Class Component example: [React Setting state inside of a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54337541/react-setting-state-inside-of-a-function)

Looking at the solution, I moved my state from `onDrop` in my div and added it to the inside of the function.

```
  const fileDrop = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const files = e.dataTransfer.files;
    if (files.length) {
      handleFiles(files);
    }
    setIsDropped(!isDropped);
  };
```

This solution for my works as intended in this project.